# The underlying provider failed on open in WCF entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to change the connection string in my application.i changed servername,intial catalog,username,password correctly but i am getting "The underlying provider failed on open in WCF entity framework?" .Please tell me how to change the connection string to publish the files in client server?

Comment: It means you probably didn't change it correctly or there is some another permission or network issue.

Comment: <add name="DataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AMI.csdl|res://*/AMI.ssdl|res://*/AMI.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Venkateswar-PC;Initial Catalog=AIM;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: i given correct credentials.please tell me what type of permissions and network issues need to provide.

Comment: Remote connections enabled, TCP protocol enabled.

Comment: yea i enabled both but again i am getting "The underlying provider failed on open
"

Comment: my system having Sqlserver2008 previously i am using that connection string it's working fine.But another system also having sqlserver restored my database in that it is wan network.just i changed the connection string credentials values to new system correctly but why i am getting.?

Comment: Look at the inner exception chain; the actual error will be in a nested exception.

Comment: while debugging the code connection is opening when publishing the files in server displaying "RequestError" .please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Please Check the Permissions to folder as "EveryOne".